# YouTube data - retrieving number of views by day for non owned video's)

Tags: youtube

I'm trying to retrieve YouTube data (number of views) by day for a specific video id & period. Till now i am only able to retrieve the total amount of views for the video by using PHP to asses YouTube statistics.

Problem: I cannot fix it to get the number of views by day 
Goal: Eventually i want to make some queries that calculates the growth i percentage by day.